# Thrift Default Enum values

Tags: enums, thrift

Using Apache Thrift and generating code in Java, I'm trying to figure if there is a way to have one of the enumerations be returned as default. 
For e.g using the following definition:

```
enum STATE {
  UNKNOWN,
  AVAILABLE,
  UNAVAILABLE
}
```

I want UNKNOWN to be returned as the default and not a NULL value so that additions to the enum do not affect existing clients. 
Is it possible to do that? What are the other options available in this case?

Comment: +1 Not much enum detail for thrift

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the part "returned as default" since there is no such thing as a default return value. What may solve your issue could be sth. like:

```
struct ReturnedValues
{
  1: STATE state = UNKNOWN  
}
```

Otherwise you should explain your case.

Comment: struct ReturnedValues
{
  1: STATE state;  
} then what is the default value of state?